# a:hover does not wrap child elements

Tags: css, hover

I have span and image inside anchor tag, the problem is when I hover them they does not hover as one.

```
<a href="">
      <img src="image"/>
      <span>Shopping Cart</span>
</a>

a :hover {
    opacity: 0.6;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j37fwdtp/1/)

any help would be appreciated. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `a :hover`, you are selecting a descendant of an `<a>` element that is being hovered. That's why they activate separately. If you remove the space (`a:hover`), it will select the `<a>` that is being hovered, which is what you want.

Comment: thank you. never knew css selectors have this feature.

Comment: If one of the answers helped you, please consider [accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it to mark the question as solved. (You can do that in another ~7 minutes.)

Answer (score 1):

problem is your space between a and (:)

```
<a href="">
      <img src="image"/>
      <span>Shopping Cart</span>
</a>

a:hover {
    opacity: 0.6;
}
```

see demo http://jsfiddle.net/JentiDabhi/7ondpajd/

Comment: wow. thanx. it worked. can u please tell me logic behind this?

Comment: you add (a :hover)  it's wrong  method is like this (a:hover)

Answer (score 0):

You could include the `<img>` in your `<span>`:

```
<a href="">
       <span><img src="image"/>Shopping Cart</span>
</a>
```

```css
a :hover {
    opacity: 0.6;
}
```

```html
<a href="">
       <span><img src="image"/>Shopping Cart</span>
</a>
```